# how much profit can I expect if I start mining today on my Gaming laptop?

Tags: mining-hardware

Is there a website/soft that can help me estimate how much I can expect to earn, based on my current hardware configuration?

P.S. I don't pay for electricity or wifi costs. Its included in my utilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing to a few penny per year, even without paying for electricity or internet it's way too slow as of end of 2016. If you want to do mining you will need to do that on alt-coin that don't rely on SHA256.

Comment: Thanks. I didnt realize this question has been asked already.